# Android: Logging on an android device

Tags: android, hardware, logcat

I am no good with hardware concepts. So I have this probably very silly doubt.

I want to add Log to my application. When running on an emulator, I know where to see the Log output - it's visible in the Logcat window of Eclipse.

I want to know where I can see these logs when I run it on a hardware device. I am using following command to load my app on to the device : `./adb install helloWorld.apk`

So where will the log be created and under what name?

Apologies if the question is vague or silly. I really do not know more details.

-Kiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
./adb logcat
```

Comment: Yes, that helps me view the log.Is there a way to filter out the other log messages and view only the ones I have logged in my app?

Comment: Do you have a common TAG you use for logging?

Comment: `adb logcat | grep "whatever"`?

Comment: Yes, a TAG is used. Is that to be given in "whatever"?..i.e adb logcat | grep "TAG"

Comment: One more little doubt..Is this logcat available as a file? I mean, if I want to do some more logging, in software layers below the android application layer, can I give the path of the same LogCat file?   When working with emulator, I observed that no such file is created as such in my workspace.

Comment: logcat is a program.
You can use: "adb logcat > log.file", then you will get your logs stored inside the log.file

Comment: hmmm, that command will save the current logcat into log.file, right? Will it continue futher logging into that file?

Answer (score 0):

When you run on device, the log is also available in LogCat. You will need to turn on USB debugging (`Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging`) in your device, then you can use LogCat just like in the emulator, both using `./adb logcat` and in Eclipse.